# Scrapy does not follow the Request url

Tags: url, request, scrapy

Following is the code. Basically, I am scraping movie info. from IMDB.com. But somehow the Request doesn't scrap the url, which is in the object "addr". The "print" I put into the parse_item2 simply does not show up.

This drives me crazy. I spent hours on it. Could anyone with some experience help? Thank you so much.

```
 # code for the spider

    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import Request, Response
    from beta.items import BetaItem
    import urllib2

    class AlphaSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'alpha'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com','imdb.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=boxoffice_gross_us&title_type=feature&year=2005,2005']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//td/a',), allow=('/title/')), callback='parse_item1'),
    )

    def parse_item1(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = BetaItem()

        idb = sel.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
        idb = idb[0].split('/')[-2]
        item['idb'] = idb

        title = sel.xpath('//h1[@class="header"]/span[@class="itemprop"]/text()').extract()
        item['title'] = title

        addr = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + idb + '/business'
        request = Request(addr, callback=self.parse_item2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        return request

    def parse_item2(self, response):
        print 'I am here'
        item = response.meta['item']
        sel = Selector(response)
        # BLA BLA BLA
        return item
```

Comment: Does `parse_item1` work? Does the page pointed to by `addr` exist?

Comment: Hi Blender, yes "idb" and "title" can be crawled.

Comment: It could just be taking a while to get to the extracted links, as Scrapy's crawl queue is LIFO. Can you test it on a specific page?

Comment: I tried, still it does not follow the request. Is there any particular requirement for a valid URL? This case the url is a utf-8 string: 'http: //www.imdb.com/title/tt0360717/'. (space added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem is indeed as Blender said in his comment above. It takes quite some time to crawl stuff for some particular request.